# configure httpd.conf to accept 1,000 connctions - How

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I would like to edit my httpd.conf to accept max of 1,000 clients connections.
this is what I have now:

```
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000



StartServers         2
MaxClients         150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
```

How should I edit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have enough RAM to serve the requests, and you are using the prefork multi-processing module, you can use the 2 directives `MaxClients` and `ServerLimit` to set the total number of simultaneous requests that will be served;

To check for prefork run `apachectl -V | grep MPM` and look for the following output;

```
#  apachectl -V | grep MPM
Server MPM:     Prefork
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
```

The [MaxClients](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients) directive sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be served.

> Any connection attempts over the MaxClients limit will normally be
>   queued, up to a number based on the ListenBacklog directive. Once a
>   child process is freed at the end of a different request, the
>   connection will then be serviced.

But the `ServerLimit` also puts a maximum limit on the number of processes that apache will spawn to serve requests.

> For the prefork MPM, the ServerLimit directive sets the maximum configured value
>   for MaxClients for the lifetime of the Apache process..

hence I would go for something like;

```
ServerLimit 1000   
MaxClients 1000
```

---

Alternatively for `For the worker MPM, this directive in combination with ThreadLimit sets the maximum configured value for MaxClients for the lifetime of the Apache process. Any attempts to change this directive during a restart will be ignored` workers [ThreadLimit docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html)